# How to access derived objects in base class container without direct inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I know I can cast *pointer to base class* in a container to *pointer to derived class* with the help of `static_cast<derived_class*>(base_class_ptr)`.

However what can I do if they are not directly related, but only have a common child.
Look at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Item
{
public:
    Item(std::string name): _name(name) { /* */ };

private:
    std::string _name;
};
class Readable
{
public:
    Readable(std::string content): _content(content) { /* */ };
    virtual auto content(void) const -> std::string
    {
        return this->_content;
    }

private:
    std::string _content;
};
class Book: public Item, public Readable
{
public:
    Book(std::string name, std::string content): Item(name), Readable(content) { /* */ };
};

class Person
{
public:
    auto read(const Readable& readable) const  noexcept
    {
        std::cout << readable.content() << '\n';
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    auto i0 = std::make_unique<Item>("Pot");
    auto i1 = std::make_unique<Item>("Shoe");
    auto b0 = std::make_unique<Book>("Death of a Salesman", "Blablablabla...");

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> container;
    container.emplace_back(std::move(i0)); 
    container.emplace_back(std::move(i1)); 
    container.emplace_back(std::move(b0)); 

    Person jonnie{};
    jonnie.read(static_cast<Readable*>(container[2].get())) // Error!
}
```

I want to read a `Book` from the `Item`s container, and that should be ok, because it is inherits from `Readable`, but I can't, because the compiler complains:

```
static_cast from 'pointer' (aka 'Item *') to 'Readable *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed
```

What can I do in such a case? Is there a clean solution?

Comment: As a side note, I would seriously question my design if it requires me to do downcasts. The type system and type checking rules have been designed to avoid type errors, and you are guaranteed that if the compiler doesn't find type errors, such errors cannot occur at runtime. Performing a downcast is like tearing a whole into the type system and checking rules, and there are no guarantees anymore. That's why I take downcasts as an indicator of bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to cast objects around that are required to be [polymorphic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects); they require a virtual method. The easiest (and I think in this case the best) is to make the destructor `virtual` for all the base classes, e.g.;

```
class Item
{
public:
    virtual ~Item() { /* */ };
    // .. the rest of the class
};
```

This allows [`dynamic_cast<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to work at runtime (it works with polymorphic types), it will check for and cast the object appropriately. One caveat here (given the sample use in the OP) is that you will almost certainly have to check the return value against `nullptr` to check the cast succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a `Book`, you should cast it to a `Book` (which is derived from `Item`).

The `Book` can then be used as a `Readable`, beacuse it *is*. But the `Item` is not.

Comment: I get a really fascinating error message from this, may be a bug in clang: `main(62141,0x7fff7efa2000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9d28c03130: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6`. However I do not want to cast to `Book*`, because I may want to put that cast into another function and use it for items that are readable as well such as `Sign*` or `Tome*`